# laravel excel add flash message instead of NoTypeDetectedException

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

I'm using [laravel excel](https://laravel-excel.com/) package to upload and use excel files with laravel. When I upload a file with unsupported format (E.g.:- .doc file) I get this exception.

> Maatwebsite \ Excel \ Exceptions \ NoTypeDetectedException No message

But instead I need to use a flash message like this.

```
flash("Sorry you are using a wrong format to upload files.")->error();
return Redirect::back();
```

This is my code.

```
$file = $request->file('file');
Excel::import(new MyImport, $file);
```

This is my import file

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;

class MyImport implements ToModel
{

    public function model(array $row)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import the exception at the top of your file:

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Exceptions\NoTypeDetectedException;
```

And use a [try-catch](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) block to catch the exception:

```
try {
    Excel::import(new MyImport, $file);
} catch (NoTypeDetectedException $e) {
    flash("Sorry you are using a wrong format to upload files.")->error();
    return Redirect::back();
}
```